# Why is my custom pipe designed to bypass Angular 8 security using [Innerhtml] not working? Error message 'undefined'

Tags: angular, angular8, innerhtml, angular-pipe, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am creating a dynamic angular web app and when reading information from my database, whilst I have accommodated html by replacing all occurrences of `\n` to `<br />`, angular 8 will just render this html code as text instead of new line breaks appearing.

In order to convert the static `<br />` 's into line breaks (html code) I have created a custom pipe and tried using `[InnerHtml]`. However, this not will work, and now instead of my database entries being displayed by the web-page, the message 'undefined' just appears instead.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Below is the code for my custom pipe:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Below is my app.compoment.ts with the relevant imports included:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtmlPipe } from './pipe';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

template: `
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="html">
<div [innerHtml]="html">
</div>
`,

})
export class AppComponent {

name: string;
html: string;

  constructor() {

    this.name = 'Angular8';
    this.html = "<br />";
  }
```

Below is the usage of my [InnerHtml] and my custom pipe on my trees.component.html page.

```
<div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml"  class="container" *ngFor="let tree of this.trees"><br>

        {{tree.p1}}
        {{tree.t2}}

</div>
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated on this and thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand too much, your pipe is about innerHtml, and you has a div with `[innerHTML]' and elements inside the div

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use HTML markup to separate lines? If there is no longer any html content, then you can simply paste the text into the `<pre>` tag or add to your div block style `white-space: pre`.
In your case innerHtml rewrite all content into the div block

Comment: yes due to the complexity of the webapp and the ability for users to edit the web app content, I will need to use HTML markup to separate lines.